# Title font changes when tried to bold titlesec font in Latex

Tags: fonts, latex, typography

I want to bold the words 'Professional experience' in Latex. Using `\textbf` changes the font of the words which was previously there. I tried placing `\textbf` in multiple positions in the same line but didn't work.
Here is the code and screenshot of the output. Please help.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,bottom = 0.6in,left = 0.6in,right = 0.6in,top = 1cm]{geometry}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%for color
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{70,70,200}

\newcommand{\xfilll}[2][1ex]{
\dimen0=#2\advance\dimen0 by #1
\leaders\hrule height \dimen0 depth -#1\hfill}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}

\begin{document}
\section*{{\LARGE \color{myblue} {Professional Experience}}\xfilll[0pt]{0.5pt}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

After adding `\textbf`, I see this output with font changed.

[image]

Comment: You'll need to find a font which has bold small caps - the default font does not have them

Comment: The log file will tell you about this `Font shape OT1/cmr/bx/sc undefined(Font) using OT1/cmr/bx/n instead`

Comment: Thanks for the keywords @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
Useful links: 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615212/how-make-section-titles-bold-and-small-caps

and

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27411/small-caps-and-bold-face

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to get a font which does contain bold small caps:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,bottom = 0.6in,left = 0.6in,right = 0.6in,top = 1cm]{geometry}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%for color
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{70,70,200}

\newcommand{\xfilll}[2][1ex]{
\dimen0=#2\advance\dimen0 by #1
\leaders\hrule height \dimen0 depth -#1\hfill}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}

\begin{document}
\section*{{\LARGE \color{myblue} \textbf{Professional Experience}}\xfilll[0pt]{0.5pt}}
\end{document}
```

[image]